# Continually get index of -1 when using Cursor.getType()

Tags: java, android, cursor

So I'm trying to do some simple research on my own into different types of columns in the cursors for an SMS app, but when trying to get the type of the columns, I continually get -1 as an index. I've even hard coded in column number 0 and it still reverts to -1 for some reasons. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm at a loss for words with what's going on.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String tempUri = "content://mms-sms/conversations";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(tempUri);

    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    items = new ArrayList<>();
    int length = c.getColumnCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        Log.i(TAG, "" + i);
        Items item = new Items();
        Log.i(TAG, "" + i);
        item.columnName = String.valueOf(c.getType(0));
        Log.i(TAG, "" + i);

        items.add(item);
    }

    setListAdapter(new Adapter(this, R.id.list_item, items));
}
```

The error occurs in the for loop when calling c.getType(). Right now it's hard coded and I still get the same error. I've copied the stack trace below:

```
01-28 17:40:03.050  29753-29753/com.bluhmann.testapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.bluhmann.testapp, PID: 29753
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bluhmann.testapp/com.bluhmann.testapp.MainActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 9
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2336)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5273)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
 Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 9
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getType(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:130)
        at android.database.CursorWrapper.getType(CursorWrapper.java:146)
        at com.bluhmann.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5940)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
```

P.S. Missing some bottom lines of the stack trace... It won't go into the code format, but it's the very end so I'm not sure how useful it will be. If it's needed I'll try and figure out how to get it into code.

P.P.S. Using getColumnName() works fine with the same code, and both are supposed to give back the result based on the zero based index, so I don't see why one method doesn't work and the other does.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the Cursor's index to a row that has data before you check data types. For example:

```
c.moveToFirst();
```

Though the column names will always be the same - which is why the `getColumnName()` method works as is - types are tied to individual values in SQLite, so types aren't available per column, but rather per value.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's one year late but i think it doesn't hurt to try to explain this with a bit more detail.

A table uses two indices. The one you're setting to 0 is the column index. However you didn't set the row index as Mike M. explained before, thus it remained on -1.

If you want to iterate through all fields, i'd recommend a `do{}while();` loop containing a `for(item:list)` loop like this:

```
String[] colNames = cursor.getColumnNames();
int colIndex;
int rowIndex;
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { // sets the cursor position / row index to 0
    do {
        rowIndex = cursor.getPosition();
        for ( String colName : colNames ) {
            colIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(colName);
            Log.i(TAG, 
                "Column Name: " + colName +
                "Current Row: " + Integer.toString(rowIndex) +
                "\nType = " + Integer.toString(cursor.getType(colIndex)) /*+
                "\nValue" + cursor.getString(index)
                or cursor.getInt(index)
                or cursor.getFloat(index)
                or cursor.getLong(index)
                etc.
                You can compare the type from cursor.getType(index)
                  with the Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_* constants
                */);
        }
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

This way you always have the name of the current column available plus the index  of the current row, allowing you to identify the exact field you are looking at while debugging.

The methods `moveToFirst()` and `moveToNext()` return boolean values: true if the row exists, false if not.

The `getColumnName(int)` doesn't require the row index as merely contains the names of the columns, that's why you have no problem on that line when using the column index 0. As you see there is also a method to get all column names as array, used in the above example.

Sadly there does not seem to be a way to retrieve the types if no values are present. Correct me if i'm wrong here.